# Do I need Mono for using F# with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code

I have installed .net core on my Linux Box (Ubuntu) and created the ubiquitous "Hello World" app as follows:

```
dotnet new console -lang F# -o HelloWorld
```

The previous command followed by a `dotnet restore` and `dotnet run` is all I needed to run the app. Then I decided to use Visual Studio Code as a convenient Editor/Debugging environment. After some googling it turns out that I need the [Ionide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/getting-started/getting-started-vscode) plugin in order to use Visual Studio Code with F# (and the plugin in turn relies on mono).

Is there an alternative to this (without requiring mono?)

Comment: Ionide is the plugin all the F#ers rave over, so, don't think there is many alternatives to it

Comment: looks like it might go to .net core   https://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-fsharp/issues/78

Comment: Don't get me wrong everything really works fine but I was kinda confused of requiring mono for .net core development. So if I understand correctly it s more a question of having the .net language services available in VSCode. Thanks for the link which clarifies this. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ionide is the plugin all the F#ers rave over, so, don't think there is many alternatives to it

However looks like it might go to .net core http://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-fsharp/issues/78

It's not actually needed to do .net core development, it's a plugin to vscode that gives lots of great toys for F#, it grew up in the mono world, so needs to be ported.  (for instance, you could use Vim to write code instead )